# CSS fomaring alternately for class and id

Tags: html, css

I made a scheme for step-by-step instruction. Eventually there will be many options, buttons, way.. But at the moment I'm try to paint red the buttons that are inactive. But css is connected to the "class". How do you make an "id" that has the higher priority than the "class" used for text Formating?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x183c2t/2/)

```
<input type="button" name="coughyes" class="next action-button" id="red" value="Yes" />

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#red { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same selector and append your ID.

```
#msform .action-button#red { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Though you should use a class since you can only use an ID on the page once. Update your HTML and CSS to...

```
<input type="button" name="coughyes" class="red next action-button" value="Yes">
<input type="button" name="coughno" class="red next action-button" value="No">

#msform .action-button.red { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1x183c2t/3/

Comment: @Wanarka you should also take a look at [CSS rules priority](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm) to understand how browsers decide which rule has to be applied

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you wanted to keep the same markup, you could simply change `background-color: red;` to `background-color: red !important;`.